# Regex to return the value starting at the first number and ending at the bracket

Tags: regex

I am getting a return value of `"_sahi._div(\"1.0[4]\")"` and I only need the `1.0` number. Is there any way to create a regex that returns the first number and every character after that until the `[` ?

Comment: I'm sure there is; what have you tried?

Comment: And what language are you in?

Comment: Please post your current relevant code. If you are coding in Go, you will need to capture the number, its regex engine does not support lookaheads.

Comment: You may just use [`\d+\.\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/ruReDG/1), BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
[\d\.]+(?=\[)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PcmToG/1)